# Installing GNU Radio using PyBOMBS

Tags: gnuradio, ruamel.yaml

I am following the installation instructions on https://github.com/gnuradio/pybombs.

I get the following error message:

```
→ sudo -H pybombs prefix init ~/prefix -a myprefix -R gnuradio-default
PyBOMBS.ConfigManager - INFO - Prefix Python version is: 2.7.6
PyBOMBS - INFO - PyBOMBS Version 2.3.3a0
PyBOMBS.prefix - WARNING - There already is a prefix in `~/prefix'.
Continue using this path Y/[N]? y
PyBOMBS.ConfigManager - INFO - Prefix Python version is: 2.7.6
Alias `myprefix' already exists, overwrite Y/[N]? y
PyBOMBS.ConfigManager - INFO - Prefix Python version is: 2.7.6
PyBOMBS.prefix - INFO - Installing default packages for prefix...
PyBOMBS.prefix - INFO -
  - <ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq object at 0x7f3891d44d20>
  - <ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq object at 0x7f3891d44d70>
PyBOMBS.install_manager - INFO - Phase 1: Creating install tree and installing binary packages:
PyBOMBS.get_recipe - ERROR - Error fetching recipe `<ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq object at 0x7f3891d44d20>':
Package <ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq object at 0x7f3891d44d20> has no recipe file!
```

It seems like a mismatch in the use of ruamel.yamel. Reinstalling ruamel.yamel does not solve this:

```
→ sudo -H pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall ruamel.yaml
Collecting ruamel.yaml
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/bf/6be7b1510270d785ca53193d06ba64c2f2bd969db732d108e2a82cbc9a0e/ruamel.yaml-0.15.57-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (590kB)
Collecting ruamel.ordereddict; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and python_version <= "2.7" (from ruamel.yaml)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/2c/fa6d75dc459b371ed3b88fdbf8042785ce1655073c884fd97bdbb9f48e01/ruamel.ordereddict-0.4.13-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: ruamel.ordereddict, ruamel.yaml
  Found existing installation: ruamel.ordereddict 0.4.13
    Uninstalling ruamel.ordereddict-0.4.13:
      Successfully uninstalled ruamel.ordereddict-0.4.13
  Found existing installation: ruamel.yaml 0.15.55
    Uninstalling ruamel.yaml-0.15.55:
      Successfully uninstalled ruamel.yaml-0.15.55
Successfully installed ruamel.ordereddict-0.4.13 ruamel.yaml-0.15.57
```

I using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (for various reasons I cannot upgrade).

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyBOMBS could not cope with recent changes in ruamel.yaml where `CommentedMap` and `CommentedSeq` were no longer subclasses of `dict` resp `list` but of the abstract baseclasses `MutableMapping` resp. `MutableSequence` (from `collections.abc`). PyBombs actually checked using `isinstance()` against `dict` resp. `list`.

Installing an older version of `ruamel.yaml` (anything <= 0.15.52) should work, you can do so with `pip install 'ruamel.yaml<=0.15.52'`

In the mean time a [PR](https://github.com/gnuradio/pybombs/pull/518) was submitted and merge to fix this issue, so make sure you run with the latest version of PyBOMBS checked out from github.

It is likely that your `config.yml` was truncated, so make sure you restore/regenerate that one.